# Docusign InPerson Signer for Multiple signers

Tags: docusignapi

With reference to the below question - 
[Docusign API Multiple Embedded in Person Signers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31787957/6069418)

**InPerson Signer:** Since the earlier question doesn't have an answer ticked.
From my webpage (C#, Asp.Net MVC), Once the documents are uploaded to Docusign, I want the whole document to be opened in a separate tab and with multiple signers. I am able to achieve this for a single inperson signer by mentioning the ClientUserId. If there are more than one inperson signer then how will the docusign works? On every Sign, does it give my web app a response and then do I need to call the next recipient View URL.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean when you say `"I want the whole document to be opened in a separate tab and with multiple signers"`?  Can you elaborate on that?  What is the exact workflow you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, I got covered 90% of the functionality of what I wanted. Basically I was looking for - Once the envelope is uploaded, get the recipient view url based on the routing order and open it in the browser. When the first recipient signs (in front of the host) the response should come back to my app and then I should fetch the next recipient view URL and open it again. I wanted the IN-Person Signer functionality but without sending initial email, instead I wanted the document to be opened in browser.

Comment: The next thing I'm trying to achieve is, Once the signing is FINISHED an email should be sent to recipients as COMPLETED.

Comment: I think I got what I want - Under Preferences -> Features Select - "Use Envelope Complete Email for Embedded Signers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recipient View URL will provide you the URL to open the docusign document for the first signer. Once the recipient signs and clicks on FINISH, the response URL should contain the envelope ID as the query string parameter. Add a new Action method to accept the envelope id as query string parameter. Fetch the recipient list by using **EnvelopesApi.ListRecipients** method. Check the **recepientList.CurrentOrder** property which states the next person in the line to sign. Fetch the recipient view url of the next person and redirect to the new url again. Repeat this process until the CurrentOrder is null.