# DocuSign multiple embedded signers

Tags: docusignapi

With reference to two existing questions on this topic([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31787957/docusign-api-multiple-embedded-in-person-signers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706501/docusign-inperson-signer-for-multiple-signers?noredirect=1&lq=1)), I'm still confused and I would like to reopen this topic.

So the flow in my app is the following:
1. Seller goes to the buyer, they agreed on the order and they complete the order;
2. Immediately after they click on Complete Order, an embedded signing page is opened and both seller and buyer have to sign the order within the same page

**Is this possible without opening two recipients views - one for the buyer and one for the seller? Can we achieve this just by opening one view where both recipients can sign the order?**

I tried to add a single recipient with two signing boxes, but when I change the signature in one box, automatically the second one is changed, so we cannot achieve this flow.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DocuSign will not allow you to make a single session for two unique signers. You will need to define two separate recipients and generate a different signing view for each one.

After a user clicks 'Complete Order', your application will need to generate the signing session for one signer (you'll need to determine who goes first). Once they've signed, they'll be sent to the redirect URL - at that point your application can generate the second signing session URL.